# Separating digits of a number

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, math, solution

I am writing a program to receive a positive number and output each digit separately. For instance, if the input is 692, the program should output 2, 9, 6.

I have to use while loop and separate the digits using a modulus operator (%).

The digits should be separated **without treating the number as a string** and in a mathematical way.

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="column1">
    <div class="input">
      <button onclick="problem_09()"> Run the program </button>
    </div>
    <strong><p id="output"> </p></strong>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function problem_09() {
    var outputObj = document.getElementById("output");
    var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));
    var digits = "";

    while(a >= 0){
        var d = a % 10;
        outputObj.innerHTML= "number: "+a+"<br><br>its digits: " + d;
        a = Math.floor(a/10);
    }
  
    outputObj.innerHTML = outputObj.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + "program ended";
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="column1">
    <div class="input">
      <button onclick="problem_09()"> Run the program </button>
    </div>
    <strong><div id="output"> </div></strong>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function problem_09() {
  var outputObj = document.getElementById("output");
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number: ", ""));
  var digit = "";
  outputObj.innerHTML = ""
  while(a > 0){
    let num = a%10
    a = Math.floor(a/10)
    digit += "<p>"+num+"</p>"
  }
  outputObj.innerHTML = digit + "<br><br>" + "program ended";
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("disabled","true");
}
```

Working Codepen: https://codepen.io/TheKetan2/pen/rNLOrGR

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: The digits should be separated without treating the number as a string and in a mathematical way. Do you know any other way?

Comment: Your solution appears to work properly too. Is it showing any errors?

Comment: It only outputs the first digit of the number. For example when I enter 455, it outputs number:4, digits:4.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Added full working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, take the remainder modulo 10 and divide by 10. In simple code,

```
num = some number
while (num>0):
    print(num%10)
    num = num/10
```